# How to redraw a Table in angular Data Table

Tags: javascript, angular, datatable, angular-datatables

I was able to generate datatable with the code below, but how to redraw this generated table with a new set of columns?
I tried to rerender, reload functions of angular datatable, but no luck.

Code to fetch data from server:

```js
vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise(function() {
    console.log(response)
    var defer = $q.defer();
    defer.resolve(response.previewData);
    return defer.promise;
}).withPaginationType('full_numbers');
```

Code to generate column dynamically:

```js
for(var i=0;i<response.head.length;i++) {
    vm.dtColumns.push(DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(response.head[i])
        .withTitle(response.head[i]))
}
```

Comment: You must recreate the table completely.

Comment: Thank you for your input,it worked.